# LuaLaTeX changes font smoothing with polyglossia or fontspec (and math looks weird)

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, polyglossia, latin-modern

I’m using LuaLaTeX to typeset some mathematical documents in Polish. I use the `lmodern` font family, along with `polyglossia` and `fontspec` to get diacritical characters. However, whenever I add `\usepackage{fontspec}` or `\usepackage{polyglossia}` to a file, the font smoothing visibly changes, and the math font looks bleaker and lighter than the text font. Example file, with and without `fontspec`, produces the output below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\(Hello\ world,\ Math\) mode ąęłóż
\emph{Hello world, Text} mode ąęłóż
\end{document}
```

[image: fontspec changing font smoothing]

Comment: Welcome! Don't use **lmodern**. If you load **polyglossia** or **fontspec**, the opentype version of the fonts will be used, which is probably what you want. You might want to look into **lm-math**. Possibly.

Comment: Which pdf viewer are you using? This looks very much like a viewer issue rather than anything else. in Adobe reader, they all look identical. I suspect, it is the difference in rendering between type1 fonts (used without fontspec) and OFT fonts (used with it). The math part always look the same on both as the type 1 font is used in both cases

Comment: @cfr From lm-math docs: “For use with LuaLATEX or X∃LATEX, sup­port is avail­able from the uni­code-math pack­age.” Using unicode-math leads to conflicts with amsmath, and various unusual errors like “TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [semantic nest size=500]. \end{align}”.

Comment: @ArTourter This is Okular on Linux, and is most likely the source of the difference. Sadly, `unicode-math` seems to be broken.

Comment: @ChrisWarrick It was only a suggestion. As others have said, the viewer is the most likely explanation for differences. (Try comparing printed output from the same printer.) My main point was: don't load **lmodern** with **polyglossia**/**fontspec**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is based on viewer issues.